# Axios Network Error createError.js:16 in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm new in React.Js, and have some problem when getting data from Node.js API. It gives the following error :

```
Error: Network Error
    createError createError.js:16
    handleError xhr.js:83
    dispatchXhrRequest xhr.js:80
    xhrAdapter xhr.js:12
    dispatchRequest dispatchRequest.js:52
    promise callback*request Axios.js:61
    method Axios.js:76
    wrap bind.js:9
    getMemberList service.jsx:8
    Ember 2
    React 6
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:653
    React 10
    js index.js:8
    Webpack 7
service.jsx:14
```

I tried the API with Postman and its working fine. Accessing the API from mobile app is working too. Backend is using Express and already put cors inside it. I put this inside index.js in backend

```
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
```

This is my code from react :

```
export async function getMemberList() {
    await Axios.get("http://localhost:6000/api/v1/spesialisasi/", {headers}).then(
        (res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }
    ).catch(
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    )
}
```

This is the log from network tab in inspect element

[image]

Any advice for this? Thank you.

Comment: What's the browser's http log, 500 ?

Comment: @Iry it shows nothing, just block icon, I put the log in the question, is that what you mean?

Comment: Do you happen to be running any ad-blocking extensions in your browser?

Comment: @Phil Nope. I try to access https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums and I'm able to get the data. I tried using chrome, and it says unsafe port

Comment: Sorry, what does jsonplaceholder have to do with my question? Are there any error messages recorded in the browser console?

Comment: could you also share the headers and import statement of axios

Comment: @Phil Sorry, I'm just saying it because maybe its has something to do with my code.